# Mysql Temporary table select query slowness

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating temporary table like below in my `mysql` db

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test  ( ic_id INT UNSIGNED );
```

then inserting only one value like this

```
insert into test values (1527);
```

then execute this query

```
SELECT Count(ai.id) 
FROM   car_details AS cd, 
       car_invoices AS ai, 
       numbers AS pn 
WHERE  cd.car_invoice_id = ai.id 
       AND cd.number_id = pn.id 
       AND cd.code = 'R' 
       AND ai.car_id IN (SELECT ic_id 
                         FROM   test);
```

Above query takes lot of time to execute, but follow same query without temporary table is executing very quickly

```
SELECT Count(ai.id) 
FROM   car_details AS cd, 
       car_invoices AS ai, 
       numbers AS pn 
WHERE  cd.car_invoice_id = ai.id 
       AND cd.number_id = pn.id 
       AND cd.code = 'R' 
       AND ai.car_id IN ( 1527 );
```

What is the reason for that ?

My `max_heap_table_size` is 16777216 and,
`tmp_table_size` is 16777216,

How can i fix this issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: After ea. query with the two table types, run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; See if there is a difference in `Created_tmp_disk_tables`.`Select_range`,`Select_scan` etc. and report back.

Comment: SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; shows some information but i have no idea what you ask me to compare, can you please explain it little, btw my first query is not finish even after for 7 minutes